# Authentication error when trying to connect to yahoo using imap

Tags: javascript, java, maven, jakarta-mail

I am using the below code to read text inside the body of the mail, but getting an error on while connecting to the server:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.sun.mail.iap.ProtocolException;
import com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder;
import com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol;

import javax.mail.Message;

public class test1 {

    public static void readInboundEmails() {
//create session object
        Session session = getImapSession();
        try {
//connect to message store
            Store store = session.getStore("imap");
            store.connect( "imap.mail.yahoo.com", "username", "password");
//open the inbox folder
            IMAPFolder inbox = (IMAPFolder) store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
//fetch messages
            Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
//read messages
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                Message msg = messages[i];
                Address[] fromAddress = msg.getFrom();
                String from = fromAddress[0].toString();
                String subject = msg.getSubject();
                Address[] toList = msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO);
                Address[] ccList = msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC);
                String contentType = msg.getContentType();
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in reading EMails : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in reading EMails : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in reading EMails : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static Session getImapSession() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
        props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.host", "imap.mail.yahoo.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "993");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        session.setDebug(true);
        return session;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readInboundEmails();
    }
}
```

when I run this java class by adding username and password then getting below error

```
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "imap.mail.yahoo.com", port 993, isSSL true

\* OK Welcome! IMAP Server up and ready to accept your request

A0 CAPABILITY

\* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=OAUTHBEARER ID MOVE NAMESPACE XYMHIGHESTMODSEQ UIDPLUS LITERAL+ CHILDREN UNSELECT X-MSG-EXT OBJECTID IDLE ENABLE UIDONLY X-ALL-MAIL X-UIDONLY LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS SPECIAL-USE PARTIAL APPENDLIMIT=41697280

A0 OK CAPABILITY completed

DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN

DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2

DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: OAUTHBEARER

DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=imap.mail.yahoo.com, user=username, password=\<non-null\>

DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed

DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 NO \[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED\] AUTHENTICATE Invalid credentials

Exception in reading EMails : \[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED\] AUTHENTICATE Invalid credentials
```

Please help me out on this.

Comment: The subject is incorrect. You are not having a problem reading the body of the email. If the application is not able to authenticate it will never read the body. You have an authentication issue instead.

Comment: @aled ohh yes, can you please help me with this authentication issue?
or Do you know how to can read the body of the email? because I want to verify my email using automation script